# Найти наибольший элемент среди тех строк, в которых все элементы различны

Tags: c, массивы

В программе в начале вводится размерность массива, а потом его элементы.
Далее действует функция, который находит максимальный элемент среди строк, где нет повторяющихся элементов

Например:

Массив 3х4

Элементы:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 7
8 9 10 10
```

Программы выводит ответ 10, хотя должен выводить ответ 4

Другой пример:

Массив 3х4

```
1 54 6 6
1 2 5 10
56 6 0 6
```

Вывод максимум - 6, что неверно вообще.

Подскажите, как изменит логику, чтобы все высчитывалось верно и что добавить, чтобы выводилось сообщение о том, что строк с различными элементами - нет.
Заранее спасибо

```
int ras(int a[10][10], int *n, int *m)
{
    int i, j, jj, p, max, max_prom, p2;
    max = a[0][0];
   for (i=0; i<*n; i++)
   {
    p = 0; // schetchik povtor. chisel
    p2 = 0; //metka, esli v stoke est povtori
     for (j=0; j<*m; j++)
     {
      max_prom = a[0][0];
        for (jj = 0; jj<*m; jj++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == a[i][jj]) p++;
            if (a[i][j] > max_prom) max_prom = a[i][j];
        }

        if (p==1)   //esli vstretilsya tolko etot element napr a[1][1] == a[1][1]
            {
                p = 0;
            }
        if (p > 1)
            {
                p2 = 1;
                break;   //esli vstretilos bolshe, napr. : a[1][1] = a[1][3]
            }
   }

   if (p2 == 1)
   {
    if (max_prom > max) max = max_prom;
   }


  }

   return max;
}
```

Это реализованно в виде отдельной функции.

Comment: использовать только стандартную библиотеку stdio.h

Comment: поиск элементов только перебором элементов и логикой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
char is_different(int * row; int len; int * max) {
  *max = row[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      if (row[i] == row[j])
        return false;
    }
    if (row[i] > *max)
      *max = row[i];
  }
  return true;
}

int get_max(int ** a, int n, int m) {
  int res = -1;  // Вернем, если нет ни одной строки с разными элементами
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int max_row;
    if (is_different(a[i], m, &max_row) && (max_row > res))
      res = max_row;
  }
  return res;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Если я правильно понял Ваш код, то для его работоспособности, вместо

> `if (p==1)   //esli vstretilsya tolko etot element napr a[1][1] == a[1][1]
>               {
>                   p = 0;
>               }
>           if (p > 1)
>               {
>                   p2 = 1;
>                   break;   //esli vstretilos bolshe, napr. : a[1][1] = a[1][3]
>               }
>      }
>      if (p2 == 1)
>      {
>       if (max_prom > max) max = max_prom;
>      }
>     }`

Нужно написать

```
if (p == 1 && max_prom > max)
  max = max_prom;
```

но зачем Вы прогоняете цикл по `jj` от 0, а не от `j + 1` - для меня загадка

Comment: А можно ли как-то обойтись без использования строк? 
В том виде, как у меня, но подправив логику?

Comment: @Frip Извините, но Вашу логику я так и не понял. Назначение переменных `max_prom`, `p`, `pp` для меня загадка

Comment: max_prom - максимальный промежуточный. Идет проверка строки и ищется максимальный элемент, но мы не можем поместить его сразу в max если есть повторы в строке. 

p - счетчик повторов в строке, т.е. если повторы есть, то программа не будет сравнивать max и max_prom.

p2 - для прочих вычислений, там комментарий есть

Comment: @Frip Дополнил ответ

Comment: по поводу jj:

i - смена строк
j - смена столбцов
jj - для того, чтобы сравнить текущий j с другими элементами строки с начала, соглашусь, быть может я тут неверно и нелогично поступил.

Теперь по поводу ваших поправок.
Если заменить весь текущий код вашей правкой то ничего не произойдет, ибо он пройдет цикл с  jj и будет p априори больше 1, а p2 как раз таки было для этого случая, индексировать, были ли повторы чисел, чтобы потом получить верное вычисление относительно строки

Comment: `будет p априори больше 1` с какого перепугу? Если р - это число повторов, то оно будет содержать число повторов (или число повторов + 1, если цикл по `jj` будет стартовать с числа не превышающего `j`).

Comment: Ну как бы, мы берем j-ый элемент i-ой строки и сравниваем его со всеми другими элементами данной строки, если число повторов больше чем 1 (1 - элемент сравнивается сам с собой), то переходит к другому j. А если заменить, как вы сказали, то получается, мы можем и не получить повторов j в строке, и присвоить ему максимальное значение, но вот дальше в строке может быть повторы, поэтому такая замена не будет иметь смысла в данном случае, надеюсь верно выразился

Comment: @Frip Это в моем коде оно переходит. А в Вашей "логике" идет сканирование до конца строки.

Comment: я пробовал заменить так, как вы сказали. Ничего верного программа не выводит

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Ваша функция некорректная. Она не может работать с двумерными массивами. И кроме того, так как вы имеете дело со знаковыми целыми числами, то совершенно не исключено, что максимальный элемент может быть равен -1. В этом случае результат возврата функции трактуется не однозначно.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Про -1 я с Вами полностью согласен. Но тут мы имеем дело с некорректной постановкой задачи, где не описано, что должна возвращать функция, если в матрице нет ни одной строки с различными элементами. Нужен некий null. А про двумерные массивы не понял. Почему не будет?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov На самом деле задание корректное. Это условный поиск максимума в двумерном массиве. Что касается  двумерных массивов, то типы T[M][N] не совместимы с типом T **, и никакое приведение типов не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала следует сказать несколько слов об объявлении вашей функции.

```
int ras(int a[10][10], int *n, int *m);
```

Я не увидел, где в функции меняются переменные `n` и `m`, а потому не понятно, почему они передаются по ссылке через указатели на них. Это делает интерфейс более запуьанным, и, более того, делает невозможным вызов функции, когда в качестве аргументов используются не переменные, а некоторые выражения, как, например, целочисленная константа 10. Компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке, так как он не сможет взять адрес временного объекта. Поэтому данное объявление параметров функции неверное. Проще и правильнее объявить эти два параметра следующим образом

```
int ras(int a[10][10], int n, int m);
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Но еще лучше, когда эти параметры имеют тип `size_t`, так как это тот тип, который имеют значения, возвращаемые оператором `sizeof`, который часто используется для вычисления числа элементов в массивах.

Следовательно объявление функции должно выглядеть по крайней мере следующим образом

```
int ras(int a[10][10], size_t n, size_t m);
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Параметры функций, объявленные как Массивы, неявно преобразуются в тип указателей на свои элементы. Поэтому выше-приведенное объявление эквивалентно следующему объявлению

```
int ras(int ( *a )[10], size_t n, size_t m);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Так как число элементов в каждой "строке" этого массива известно, то незачем задавать их в качестве параметра. Можно было бы объявление функции просто записать как

```
int ras(int ( *a )[10], size_t n);
```

Но в таком случае вы можете работать только с массивами, которые имеют ровно 10 элементов в каждой "строке". В этом случае вы не сможете использовать эту функцию для тех примеров массивов, которые вы привели в своем вопросе.

Поэтому, если компилятор поддерживает объявление массивов переменной длины, то лучше объявить функцию следующим образом

```
int ras( size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n] );
```

В этом случае первые два параметра определяют, сколько, соответственно, "строк" в массиве, и сколько элементов в каждой "строке".

Есть еще одна проблема. Массив может не содержать ни одной строки с уникальными элементами. Что тогда возвращать из функции?

Поэтому лучше из функции возвращать указатель на найденный максимальный элемент или `NULL` в случае, когда таковой не был найден.

Таким образом мы пришли к окончательному объявлению функции

```
int * ras( size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n] );
```

Ниже представлено определение этой функции. Только функция переименована, так как текущее имя `ras` совершенно не понятно.

```
int * max_unique_element( size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n])
{
    int *max = NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        int *row_max = &a[i][0];
        int unique = 1;

        for (size_t j = 1; unique && j < n; j++)
        {
            size_t k = 0;
            while (k < j && a[i][k] != a[i][j]) ++k;

            unique = k == j;
            if (unique && *row_max < a[i][j]) row_max = &a[i][j];
        }

        if (unique && (max == NULL || *max < *row_max)) max = row_max;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Вызов функции может выглядеть, например, следующим образом

```
    #define M 3
    #define N 4

            //...

    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 54, 6, 6 },
        { 1, 2, 5, 10 },
        { 56, 6, 0, 6 }
    };

    int *max = max_unique_element(M, N, a);

    if (max)
    {
        printf("The maximum value is %d at row %zu and col %zu\n",
            *max, ( size_t )(max - (int *)a) / N, ( size_t )(max - (int *)a) % N);
    }
```

Comment: @AndyShevchenko int a[x][y] и int * a[] - это совершенно два разных типа, которые не совместимы между собой. Тем более, int a[x][y] не эквивалентно int *a.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko Это не имеет значение, C это или C++. Массив, используемый в выражениях неявно преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент. Поэтому когда вы имеете массив типа int a[x][y], то он преобразуется к указателю с типом int ( * )[y]. Типы int ( * )[y] и тип int * - это два разных типа. Между ними нет неявного преобразования.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko Это просто позволяет сделать программу самодокументируемой.